# impress.js - how to add next and previous buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, impress.js

i found this:

```
impress().next();
impress().prev();
impress().goto(10);
```

but i dont know how to use it? is there any way to implement two simple buttons which go one slide further or back?

Comment: you simply have to create two buttons and add click events on the buttons who will in their function body will have the above function calls

Comment: This Example could help you: [jquery](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-next-example/)

Answer (score 3):

Alright I figured it out:

```
<button id="prev"></button>
<button id="next"></button>


$("#next").click(function () {
   api.next();
});

$("#prev").click(function () {
   api.prev();
});
```

That's it, easier than i thought it is.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question :)

Comment: Hi, where does the JS itself actually go? The footer? The impress.js file?