# impress.js - Next and Previous buttons

Tags: javascript, impress.js

I've looked at the other questions on this topic, and know that I have to do something like this:

I've created buttons:

```
<button id="next"></button>
<button id="prev"></button>
```

And then at the bottom of the page, I have this (this was taken from the other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703496/impress-js-how-to-add-next-and-previous-buttons)):

```
<script src="js/impress.js"></script>
<script>impress().init();</script>

<script>
$("#next").click(function () {
   api.next();
});

$("#prev").click(function () {
   api.prev();
});
</script>
```

But it isn't working at all; can someone give me a hand with this?

Answer (score 1):

it works, if next-prev are in inside impress div

```
$('#next').on('click', function(e){
    impress().next();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('#prev').on('click', function(e){
    impress().prev();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: So, how is this functionally different from the answer already posted?

Comment: e.stopPropagation(); if nav is inside impress wrap impress().next(); doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Replace your script this way:

```
<script>
$("#next").click(function () {
   impress().next();
});

$("#prev").click(function () {
   impress().prev();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included jQuery? If not, add this too:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```